# Very strange but very annoying JQuery mobile issue

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I got JQuery mobile installed and JQuery Mobile UI.

I try to use the JQuery accordeon tabs.

```
    <div data-demo-html="true">         
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I want to change the header size by for example adding

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" class="SystemAccordeonHeading">
```

*Class:*
**SystemAccordeonHeading**

Now whatever I try :

```
.SystemAccordeonHeading {
font-size: 9vw !important;
}
```

It refuses it's new style and it remains tiny....
Probably I have overlooked something but the JQuery documentation is a bit shabby at this point.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with your code and everything looks like is working as expected.  http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/6y24qbz9/ Make sure your library is loading fine, you don't have any typos and all the html and css is correct, etc. Sometimes a minor error can give you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @RicardoNuñez thank you. However also in your example the heading at the tab does not resize.

Maybe I wronly described it. But that is where I am after.

Comment: does whatever mobile platform you're using actually accept vw as units?  I've had issues with that in the past.

Comment: to change the header you need to also apply the css to the header. Check my jsfiddle update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class to -

```
.SystemAccordeonHeading a{
font-size: 9vw;
}
```

The heading is actually a link element, if you inspect the element

You do not need !important

edit -

Just be aware of, that if you put a link in your accordeon, that its font will get bigger too in this case. So I edit the class below, so you only get the headers.

```
.SystemAccordeonHeading h3 a{
font-size: 9vw;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Inspect element is a great tool, if you dont know what is going on :)

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg I edited the answer, to avoid problems, if you put links in your accordeon